# Android: OnTouch event features, detecting a normal touch, a long touch or a quick double touch

Tags: android, events, touch, detect

I need to know how i can make my activity to know when a user touches the screen, double touches it, or holding the finger on it for a long touch on a single view, with out using buttons

Could some one briefly describe me witnh what i should work here, and what logic to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some `View` or layout item that encompasses the screen, so that all the touch events are sent to it. From there, you need to attach a listener of some kind (touch or gesture, probably).

I would recommend either a [`GestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) (this supports double tapping and other gestures), or a basic touch listener (uses [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), which doesn't have double tap, but you could implement this yourself).

If you use `MotionEvent`, you can detect how long the finger has been down with `getDownTime()`. For a double tap, you can record the time of the last press (using `Calendar` or similar), then check if the last press was within some amount of time (maybe 500ms?).

If you use `GestureDetector`, you can implement these differently. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8076548/1438733) for more details (other answers in that thread provide alternatives as well). It also supports `MotionEvent` objects, so that shouldn't be a problem.